# How to prepend a character to all lines of a data string in FreeMarker?

Tags: java, freemarker, templating

I have a POJO with a multi-line string field, e.g.

```
public class Reply {
    public String body;
}
```

where content of `body` could be

```
This is
a multiline
body.
```

and I'd like produce this output

```
Hello,
this is the reply:

> This is
> a multiline
> body.

Have a nice day!
```

That is, I want to prepend the `>` character to each line of `Reply.body`.

Can I achieve this with FreeMarker? (Or any other templating engine which works with POJO instances?)

Comment: This is a simplified example for explanation purposes; the real case is more complex, so I can't simply pass a list of string splitting `Reply.body`: I need FreeMarker to prepend a character to each line of a single multiline string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<#list Reply.body?split("\n") as line>
> ${line}
</#line>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could replace the newlines with `newline` + `>`? E.g.

```
Reply.body?replace("(\n)", "\n>", 'r')
```